# File Sorting - Scanner - java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, java.util.scanner

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package filesort;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;`enter code here`
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


/**
 */

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    class recordInfo{
        int studentNumber;
        String firstName;


        public recordInfo(int studentNumber,String firstName){
            this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }
    }


    class firstNameCompare implements Comparator<recordInfo>{

        @Override
        public int compare(recordInfo t, recordInfo t1) {
            return t.firstName.compareTo(t1.firstName);
        }

    }

       class studentNumberCompare implements Comparator<recordInfo>{

        @Override
        public int compare(recordInfo t, recordInfo t1) {
            return t.studentNumber - t1.studentNumber;
        }

    }
public class FileSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{ 


        File newfile = new File("student_record.txt");


//        try{
//            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(newfile);
//                output.println("72" + "\t" +"James");
//                output.println("56" + "\t" +"Mark");
//                output.println("87" + "\t" +"John");
//                output.println("30" + "\t" +"Phillip");
//                output.println("44" + "\t" +"Andrew");
//                output.close();
//            }
//        
//        catch(IOException ex){
//            System.out.printf("error \n", ex);
//                   
//        }

       try{
            Scanner input = new Scanner(newfile);
            try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(newfile)) {
                ArrayList<recordInfo> allRecords = new ArrayList<>();
                String record = input.next();
                while (input.hasNext()){
                    String[] oneRecord = record.split(" ");
                    int studentNumber = Integer.valueOf(oneRecord[0]);
                    String firstName = oneRecord[1];
                    allRecords.add(new recordInfo(studentNumber, firstName));

                    //System.out.printf("%s %s \n", studentNumber, firstName);
                }
                Collections.sort(allRecords, new studentNumberCompare());
                for (recordInfo RecordInfo : allRecords){
                    output.println(RecordInfo.firstName);
                    output.println("\t" +RecordInfo.studentNumber);
                    output.println("\n");
                    System.out.println(" " + RecordInfo.studentNumber + " " + RecordInfo.firstName);
                }
               output.close();

            }

       }

        catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.printf("error \n", ex);

        }

    }

}
```

Basically the code is to sort records in the file called student_records.txt by student numbers arranged in ascending order. Right now, I'm getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException   at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)     at
>   filesort.FileSort.main(FileSort.java:79) Java Result: 1

ALSO, student_records.txt is empty. :/ Anyone available to help me please?

Comment: Exception has been fixed but the text file comes out empty after sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing from:

```
            String record = input.next();
            while (input.hasNext()){
```

to:

```
            while (input.hasNext()){
                String record = input.next();
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixes the error but my text file is still empty. :/

Comment: The line `try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(newfile)) {` removes the contents of `student_record.txt`. So you should move it to before the line `Collections.sort(allRecords, new studentNumberCompare());`.

Comment: Thanks I've fixed it but now I'm having a format error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "72 James"

Comment: You may have to write `input.useDelimiter("\n");` or  `input.useDelimiter("\r\n");`.

Comment: Thank you as well. I've now fixed it and my new file is sorted and formatted properly. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
 try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(newfile)) {
```

just before the output loop, that's what empties the file before scanning

and change the Scanner to a BufferedReader(from a FileReader) and use readline, since Scaner next gives onla a token.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you exactly meant. Like this? 

>>>>Collections.sort(allRecords, new studentNumberCompare());
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(newfile);
            for (recordInfo RecordInfo : allRecords){<<<<<

So I did the above but now I have an error of: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: Ok, that's the next error, Scanner.next() gives you the next token(what will be the student number at first), not the next line.

Comment: Thanks. So I've fixed it with this String record = input.nextLine(); But now there's a format error. :/  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "72 James" Didn't I already convert the string to an int?

Comment: The split didn't work, maybe the char after 72 isn't a space?

Comment: Yeah, you're right its a tab "\t", what can I do to fix it if its a tab and not a space?

Comment: use a "\\s"(any whitespace) in the split